# PHP passing variable to URL

Tags: php, url, variables

I have a variable say, $CODE, and I want to include it into another variable which is actually an URL like:
http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/datafiles/275/uurgeg_275_2011-2020.zip
so that would be:

```
$URL = "http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/datafiles/275/uurgeg_275_2011-2020.zip"
```

I want to include $CODE variable into $URL instead of number "275"
so that would be:

```
$URL = "http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/datafiles/$CODE/uurgeg_$CODE_2011-2020.zip"
```

but the problem is the 2nd $CODE inclusion because of next underline ($CODE_) to it, and when I include quotations like '$CODE', the actual quotations will appear in the $URL variable so if the $CODE variable equals to number 275 it will be like:

```
$URL = "http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/datafiles/'275'/uurgeg_'275'_2011-2020.zip"
```

which is not valid.
could you tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Surround it in `{}` as in

```
$URL = "http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/datafiles/{$CODE}/uurgeg_{$CODE}_2011-2020.zip";
```

Inside a double-quoted string, it's often a good idea to surround variables in `{}` as an aid to the parser.  It is necessary to surround complex variables like `" a string with {$object->property[0]->value} inside`, but not always necessary for simple variables.  In your case, it must be done to isolae `$CODE` from the rest of the string beginning with `_` so that it is recognizable as an existing variable.

This is explained in the [PHP Strings documentation.](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: @user945782 What do you mean  `` for a variable?

Comment: actually I am going to run a command like
` wget http://... ` which a variable ($CODE) need to be included in the URL but I don't know how to include that when ` ` is present,
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a concatenation operator:

```
$URL = "http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/datafiles/".$CODE."/uurgeg_".$CODE."_2011-2020.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

Within double qotes you can use {$code} -- this will solve your problem with the following underbar